# How to import Foundation 6.5 in Webpack-powered project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation, babeljs

I'm trying to import Foundation 6.5.3 in a project with Webpack 4.4 and getting

```
SyntaxError: "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"
    exports webpack:///./node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js?:20
    <anonymous> webpack:///./node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js?./node_modules/script-loader:1
    js http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:185
```

In my top-level JS file I'm using `script-loader` to load jQuery and Foundation files

```
// app.js

import 'script-loader!jquery'
import 'script-loader!foundation-sites/js/foundation.core'
```

Here is a webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js'])
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
          'css-loader', 
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader', 
            query: {
              includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])
  ],
  externals: {
    foundation: 'Foundation'
  }
});
```

and babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

My understanding is that one of the solutions might be to process Foundation files with babel. Sadly enough changing `exclude: /node_modules/` to `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!foundation-sites/` as it's suggested around here didn't help.

Can anyone please suggest how to fix that problem?

Comment: You don't want the script-loader. You need babel, babel-loader, babel-runtime-transform and use import `foundationt-sites/...`.

Comment: @DanielRuf can you please elaborate? I'm definitely not a JS tooling expert and probably won't figure it out in all the information flow :)

Comment: See https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/src/assets/js/app.js and https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js#L113